# Spring Security custom message for "Authentication method not supported: GET"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to override spring security message "Authentication method not supported: GET"?

In spring-security-code-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar->org/springframework/security/messages.properties there is no key to override this message.

Is there any other way to override this message?

I am only allowing server to authenticate using post method. But when I directly call /j_spring_security_check using get message then server return above message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change message override `attemptAuthentication` method of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` class, and set custom message where `AuthenticationServiceException` thrown.

Ref: [Spring Source Code Link](http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/spring-security/blobs/43be9ea2a467feecaed9027c8399553adf3499d3/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java)

--OR--

To override default behavior of spring security for postOnly request, if you don't want particular message then use following method:
`org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` will handle all authentication related exceptions. Which will handle `org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException` that was thrown when spring security configured as postOnly, so just redirect to page when this exception was thrown.

To override default configuration add below code in `applicationContext.xml`

`<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="LOGIN_ERROR_PAGE_URL" />
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop   key="org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException">REDIRECT_PAGE_URL</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>`

Answer (score 1):

When the application receives `/j_spring_security_check` request, configured subclass of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` gets invoked.

In my application it is the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`, which by default has `postOnly` set to true.

To override that postOnly to false, you need to update the bean definition of authentication processing filter as below:

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter" 
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
      p:postOnly="false" />
```

And the following change is also required in web.xml

```
<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Hope this helps you.

Shishir

Comment: I required to only allow post only but when user direct hit using browser to `/j_spring_security_check` then this message will come so just want to override this message. I dont like to support GET. So is there any way to just change message?